# Plot list of quadratics

Tags: pgfplots

I have a list of quadratic equations e.g.

```
1.32663 - 2.40708*x + 2.41377*x^2, 0.872512 - 2.3468*x + 3.95037*x^2, 1.21842 - 3.33471*x + 4.49893*x^2, ...
```

Is there any way to quickly and easily plot all of these on one single set of axes using a variety of colours (there does not have to be a unique colour for each function but it would be good to have at least a handful of colours)

Comment: Add the plots in a `\foreach` (provided by pgf) loop inside the axis environment

Answer (score 5):

You can do as [@Raven suggest](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/509695/plot-list-of-quadratics#comment1289013_509695) with one tilt, namely use `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` (see section **8.1 Utility Commands** of the pgfplots manual).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
 \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1.32663 - 2.40708*x + 2.41377*x^2, 0.872512 - 2.3468*x +
 3.95037*x^2, 1.21842 - 3.33471*x + 4.49893*x^2}{
 \addplot+[no marks] {#1};
 }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]